# How are the primes used to generate RSA keys?

Tags: rsa, public-key, prime-numbers

I am confused about how keys in RSA asymmetric encryption are generated and what the implications for open communications are.  Textbooks say the one-way function is merely two primes (with some critical constraints) -- so how do the two primes generated get turned into keys?

Does this mean that having a public key is simply having one of the primes in a translated or equivalent form?  For example, if I were to encrypt a message with someone else's public key and the one-way function could be broken by a third party, then could they decrypt the message with a key generated by the other prime?  Does the other prime have to go through some special process to become a key?

To go further, if the encrypted message was posted in a public forum or sniffed off of a wireless network, etc. (and again, the one-way function was broken by a mysterious third party), does that mean the message could be decrypted by the third party?  Would it matter which prime was used?  What i am wondering is what is the process whereby the primes behind the one-way function are converted into keys and is that process the same regardless of encryption used?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography Stack Exchange. Your question was migrated here because of being not directly related to software development (the topic of Stack Overflow), and being fully on-topic here. Please register your account here, too, to be able to comment and accept an answer.

Comment: I edited your title (and the text) to make clear this is about RSA - there are other asymmetric encryption schemes which don't use primes this way.

Answer (score 6):

> Textbooks say the one-way function is merely two primes...

Yes, that's the key part.

It turns out that if you have a number that's a product of two large primes, deducing which primes factor that number is quite difficult.

So, what we understand from this is that if you have $n = pq$, and you know $p$ and $q$, you can generate $n$, but if you have only $n$, it is hard to generate $p$ and $q$.

These are not keys by and of themselves - they're parts of a process used to find a key. Specifically, a number $e$ is chosen and then you need to find $de = 1 \mod (p-1)(q-1)$. I've covered the mathematics in detail [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/398/46), but the essential part to understand is that it is difficult to compute $p-1$ or $q-1$ without $p$ and $q$, which you don't have if you have only $n$. Thus, if you know $e$, you have no way to get to $d$ (it's important to understand it isn't theoretically impossible. It's just very, very hard practically).

$e$ and $d$ form the key - $e$ is chosen and $d$ is usually computed, although not always by the mechanism I described.

> ...if ... the one-way function could be broken by a third party, then could they decrypt the message with a key generated by the other prime?

Yes. The message wouldn't be generated by another prime in the case of RSA, but if they could somehow undo the one-way function, then the cryptosystem is broken and all your messages would be readable.

> Would it matter which prime was used?

It does not matter. They just need to be big! At one time, the choice of prime did matter, for resistance against  [Pollard's p-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_-_1_algorithm). However, it is now thought that for more advanced methods [this is not the case](https://web.archive.org/web/20130210063953/http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2217).

For Textbook RSA you can actually interchange the keys $d$ and $e$, which makes RSA a trapdoor permutation, however, in this case $d$ the product of two primes is still the private component, even though it is used in the "role" of encryption.  If things are done properly using "production quality" crypto like [PKCS# 2.2](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf) then the keys are not interchangeable as the functions for encryption and signatures are different.

> What i am wondering is what is the process whereby the primes behind the one-way function are converted into keys and is that process the same regardless of encryption used?

The $de = 1 \mod (p-1)(q-1)$ process is not the only way to relate $d$ to $e$. You can also use $\lambda(n)$, the [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), which is what happens in [PKCS#1](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf).

Other public key systems have different conversion functions, not all of which rely on the use of prime number factorisation. Common examples are the [discrete logarithm problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) and [point multiplication over elliptic curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication).